# Finding isolated/orphaned nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I find the nodes that have 0 edges? For example:

[image]

The item at the top, which is `(d:Department {name: "A42"})`, has zero edges. How can I just get those items with that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)—()
RETURN n
```

Comment: As of Neo4j 4.4.5 (probably earlier versions), this query does not work. It fails with this error: `Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, [ or '-' (line 2, column 15 (offset: 24))
"WHERE NOT (n)—()"`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Graphileon is correct, but in Neo4j 4.3+ there is a warning that this syntax will become deprecated. You can use the following instead:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((n)--())
RETURN n
```

Comment: In Neo4j 4.4.5 (probably 4.4.x), this query works. The other answer (`MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)—()
RETURN n`) no longer produces a warning as with 4.3.x, but instead does not run due to "invalid input".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation:

- show each node label, where one or more nodes is orphaned (has no relationships with any other node)
- include the count of those nodes as well

```
MATCH (x)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((x)--())
RETURN distinct(labels(x)), count(*)
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

This works as of Neo4j 4.4 (specifically, 4.4.5).